# Give access to encapsulated container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

```
class X {
  public:
    typedef std::list<int> Container;

    // (1)
    const Container& GetElements() const;

    // (2)
    Container::iterator ElementBegin();
    Container::iterator ElementEnd();

    // (3)
    CustomIterator GetElementIterator();

  private:
    Container m_container;
};
```

I'm looking for a consistent and clean way of providing iterators to encapsulated containers to the caller. I came up with the three ideas marked in the source code above.

1. Provides size(), begin() and end(), all perfect for read access. However, because the returned `Container` reference is const, you'll only be able to use `const_iterator`. Returning the reference non-const is bad, because the container itself could be modified (e.g. `clear()`).
2. Provides non-const access to the elements, however we'd often need an own `size()` method (like `GetElementCount()`). `iterator::distance()` could be used, but that may be inefficient for some containers (where `operator++`/`--` is called repeatedly to calculate the distance).
3. Provides a custom iterator with methods like `next()` etc. Still an own `size()` method is required.

I highly bet there're nicer solutions, so if you know any, I'd be glad to see them.

Comment: If you want to expose pretty much anything from the container, why not inherit from it, rather than encapsulating it ?

Comment: @Sander De Dyker: Because I don't want to extend the container in any way (STL containere are not meant to be derived, anyway). It's even likely that there's more than one container in a class like the `X` one is the example.

Comment: it's true that it's not a good idea in the general case. But in specific cases, it can be useful (assuming you know what you're doing). It seems though that's a moot point, since it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mix of (2) and (3) would probably be what I'd do :

```
class X {
  public :
    typedef std::list<int> ElementContainer;
    typedef ElementContainer::size_type ElementSizeType;
    typedef ElementContainer::iterator ElementIterator;
    typedef ElementContainer::const_iterator ConstElementIterator;

    ElementIterator elementBegin() { return m_container.begin(); }
    ElementIterator elementEnd() { return m_container.end(); }

    ConstElementIterator elementBegin() const { return m_container.begin(); }
    ConstElementIterator elementEnd() const { return m_container.end(); }

    ElementSizeType elementSize() const { return m_container.size(); }

  private :
    ElementContainer m_container;
};
```

It still leaves room to write custom iterators (by changing the `typedef`s), but as long as the ones provided by the container are ok, they can be used.

Comment: This looks like a good compromise to me. A little bit much to write, but replacable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use these names instead  : `iterator`, `const_iterator`, `begin`, `end`, `cbegin`, `cend` and `size()`  as:

```
class X 
{
  public :

    typedef std::list<int>::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::list<int>::const_iterator const_iterator ;

    iterator begin() { return m_container.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return m_container.end(); }

    const_iterator cbegin() const { return m_container.begin(); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return m_container.end(); }

    size_t size() const { return m_container.size(); }

  private :
    std::list<int> m_container;
};
```

And if you can use C++0x, then use `m_container.cbegin()` and `m_container.cend()` as:

```
const_iterator cbegin() const { return m_container.cbegin(); }
const_iterator cend() const { return m_container.cend(); }
```

Comment: I prefer using the method name as begin() rather than ElementBegin(). This makes us feel the class as a container.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of much cleaner methods; you might consider the lightweight (4) solution giving access with

```
const Container& container() const { return m_container; }
```

I would prefer (3) since the container type becomes fully encapsulated, i.e. your type does not necessarily require inclusion of  and you can change the container type without recompiling depending modules.

Comment: Your 4th proposal is exactly my 1st one, however that'd give access to const elements, only. The 3rd solution was also my initial idea, but I'm still wondering if I can't get it done with STL iterators, since they're already there. :-)

Comment: Sure you can, but remember it's not only begin and end, but also rbegin, rend and the reverse_iterator. Gets pretty messy pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Off course, the simplest is this :

```
class X {
  public:
    typedef std::list<int> Container;

    Container m_container;
};
```

but that makes your `class X` obsolete.

Other then that, if you really like your class, then add next methods :

```
Container::const_iterator ElementBegin() const;
Container::const_iterator ElementEnd() const;
int size() const;
```

Comment: Of course the class doesn't only consist of the container and access methods, that'd be completely useless. There may be loading routines or other useful methods that operate on the container.

Comment: @Tank That's not what you wrote in your question.

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear. But obviously a class that only holds a container and only gives access to it would be useless. ;-) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

2 and 3 really aren't distinct options. However, 3 as written is pretty much useless. No STL algorithm will use `CustomIterator::next`. For STL compatibility, you'd write:

```
// mix of 2 and 3
CustomIterator begin();
CustomIterator end();
```

and give `CustomIterator` the standard `operator++` and `operator*`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Boost, there is a library for you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html
Specifically look at iterator_facade and iterator_adapter

Here is an example of what to do - It provides an std::vector holder, with STL compatible iterators. You can extend it by adding other methods, like operator[], size(), push_back() etc.

template
class VectorHolder
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

public:
    VectorHolder()
        : m_values()
    {
    }

public:
    typedef typename std::vector::iterator vector_iterator;
    typedef typename std::vector::const_iterator vector_const_iterator;

```
class iterator : public boost::iterator_adaptor<iterator, vector_iterator>
{
public:
    iterator()
        : iterator::iterator_adaptor_()
    {
    }

    iterator(const vector_iterator& it)
        : iterator::iterator_adaptor_(it)
    {
    }

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
};

class const_iterator : public boost::iterator_adaptor<const_iterator, vector_const_iterator>
{
public:
    const_iterator()
        : const_iterator::iterator_adaptor_()
    {
    }

    const_iterator(const vector_const_iterator& it)
        : const_iterator::iterator_adaptor_(it)
    {
    }

    const_iterator(const iterator& it)
        : const_iterator::iterator_adaptor_(it.base())
    {
    }
private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
};


iterator begin()
{
    return iterator(m_values.begin());
}

iterator end()
{
    return iterator(m_values.end());
}

const_iterator begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(m_values.begin());
}

const_iterator end() const
{
    return const_iterator(m_values.end());
}protected:
std::vector<T> m_values;};
```