# Better interface for a class that hide container

Tags: c++, stl, interface, iterator, containers

I have `MyClass` that hide the container inside it, I want to control when new item is added to the container and when an item is to be deleted from container, but i don't need to control read-only operation such as getter function

```
class MyClass {
    protected: 
        std::vector<MySubClass> subclasses;
    public:
}
```

for interfacing with the user of `MyClass`, should I implement interface function such as :

`addSubClass()`, `getSubClassAt(int )`, `getSubClassIndex(MySubclass )`, `delSubClass()`.

or its better just return const iterator, for readonly operation :

`std::vector<MySubClass>::const_iterator getSubclassIterator()`;

and provide special write-operation function such as

`addSubClass()`, `delSubClass()`.

or is there is a better way than these?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826677/give-access-to-encapsulated-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invent your own member functions for manipulating the internal list of objects, then I will have to learn your interface when I want to use your class.

I much rather you use the conventions of the standard library, which I already know, so I can use your class immediately:

```
class MyClass {
    protected: 
        std::vector<MySubClass> subclasses;
    public:
        typedef std::vector<MySubClass>::const_iterator const_iterator;

        const_iterator begin() const {return subClasses.begin();}
        const_iterator end  () const {return subClasses.end  ();}

        void insert(const_iterator where, const MySubClass& obj);
        iterator erase(iterator pos);
        iterator erase(iterator begin, iterator end);

        // ...
}
```

Comment: This is true if MyClass is just another container class. But if MyClass is some kind of repository of domain objects for example, such an interface is not really expressive. Users of MyClass might wonder wtf the begin or and of a MyClass is, if this is meaningless for MyClass. Here an interface that talks in the domain language is much more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Your users will really appreciate it if you provide the subset of standard library container calls that apply to your container: Stuff like `push_back`, `begin`, `end`, and `find` for example. If you reinvent the interface it will be harder for clients to understand, and it won't always be compatible with standard algorithsm.