# How to hide my inner collection but allow the user iterate over him ?

Tags: c++, stl

I have many class that has inside `list<cats>` , and i want to allow users that use my class to iterate over the cats i have, so i give them access to a const iterator by writing the following function :

```
list<cats>::const_iterator GetIterator()
{
    //return the iterator
}
```

Now i want to change my implementation of the class and use vector instead of list, so i need to return a const iterator of vector.

The problem is that every one that uses my class now need to change their code from `list<cats>::const_iterator` to `vector<cat>::const_iterator`.

If all the iterators where to inherit from "forward iterator" it would be very useful.

My major question is how i solve this problem, i don't want to inherit from a collection.

Another very related question is why the designers of STL chose not to inherit iterators one from another ? (for example random access iterators could have inherit from forward iterators, he have all it's functionality)

I did pretty extensive search before i asked my question but couldn't find the solution. 
The closest thing i found to my question is this, but it is not exactly my question.
[Give access to encapsulated container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826677/give-access-to-encapsulated-container)

Comment: You may *hide* the type with a `typedef` : something like `typedef list<cats>::const_iterator cats_const_iterator;`

Comment: Note that to have a polymorphic `forward_iterator` base class, you'd need all relevant member functions to be `virtual` and you'd have to allocate the iterator somewhere long-lived (most likely: dynamically) and return a pointer to it.

Comment: The easiest solution is to NEVER write the word type::iterator. :)
Use
`auto it = getIterator ();` instead

Comment: I think one of the solution in your case is implementing some facade class providing iterating functionality. Inside that class used iterator type will be incapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

Expose an iterator type from your class, e.g:

```
class a
{
  vector<int> g;
public:
  typdef vector<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;

  const_iterator begin() const
  { return g.begin(); }

  : // etc

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the users can recompile the code you can use

```
typedef list<cats> CatList;
```

in your include file. Then, if you want to change the container, change it to

```
typedef vector<cats> CatList;
```

and the users would use e.g.

```
CatList::iterator it;
```

However this is not a good practice; the iterators of different containers may look equal but behave differently e.g. deleting an item from a vector invalidates all iterators but doing the same on list affects only iterator of deleted item. Not mentioning the case if some day you want to use `std::map<some_key,cats>`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nim's answer and wanted to offer the style I follow which I think makes maintenance easier since now changing the underlying container type requires no work at all for users of your class and very little work for you when maintaining your class.

```
class A
{
  // change only this to change the underlying container:
  // Don't Repeat Yourself!

  using container_t = std::vector<int>;               




public:

  // constructor from a copy of a container
  A(container_t source) 
  : _myContainer { std::move(source) } 
  {}

  // this derived type is part of the public interface
  using const_iterator_t = container_t::const_iterator; 

  // following your function naming style...
  const_iterator_t GetIterator() const { return /* some iterator of _myContainer */; }
  const_iterator_t GetEnd() const { return std::end(_myContainer); }


private:
  container_t _myContainer;
};
```